# Finding numbers of order 10 in various groups help.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory

So I actually have a solution, but I need help understanding it. Here is the problem.

[image]

I don't understand why the numbers relatively prime to 10 are of order 10. And also why there are none in $Z_{15}$.

Comment: The last one is an application of [Lagrange's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange's_theorem_%28group_theory%29): the subgroup generated by an element has the same size as the order of the element, but as a subgroup it has to divide the size of the group.

Comment: It is not that the numbers prime to $10$ are of order $10$. It just happens that there are the same number of elements of order $10$ as there are coprime to $10$ (and between $1$ and $10$). To see this, think  a bit more about when the formula you have give a certain result.

Comment: I know this was from awhile ago but I am studying for an exam and I still don't understand this. For the first one, I understand why [3],[9],[21],[27] are the elements that have order 10, but I still don't understand why they equate to 3xPHI(10)=3x([1],[3],[7],[9])=([3],[9],[21],[27]). Am I thinking about this wrong still?